# Do truth tables need proofs?

Tags: logic, definition

Possibly a silly question but do truth tables themselves need proofs, or are they technically considered definitions and therefore require no proof?

Comment: Proof for what?

Comment: If you have a set of propositions that are defined alreday, you logically deduce ("prove") if the operations involving them are valid or not. The table is just a way of representing them.

Comment: If I use long multiplication to find that $115 \times 27 = 3105$, do I need to prove that my work is correct? Not usually - the work itself is the proof that the final product is correct. Similarly, the truth table itself is a proof that that formula takes on particular truth values.  Both long multiplication and truth tables can be verified using very low-thought algorithms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that silly of a question.

When you 'fill out' a truth table for some propositional formula, you are, in a sense, proving that the truth table has the values it has. It is a relatively trivial and informal proof, but a proof nonetheless. Then, when you observe that, say, the truth table always results in true, you have proved the sentence is a tautology. Similarly for a contradiction, or a sentence that is satisfiable but not a tautology.

The key here is that this is an ordinary mathematical proof *about* a sentence propositional logic, not a formal proof *of* some sentence in the deductive system of propositional logic. It is a proof in the so-called *metatheory*.

There is a completeness theorem (again, a meta-theorem *about* propositional logic, not a formal theorem *of* propositional logic) that says that there is a proof of a sentence in the deductive system for propositional logic if and only if it is a tautology according to truth tables. So when you prove that a sentence is a tautology, you can use this theorem to conclude that a formal proof of this sentence exists, even though you haven't actually done the work of finding the proof.

**Edit**
Henning in the comments points out that rather than talking about truth tables for  propositional sentences, you might be asking about the underlying truth tables for the primitive connectives $\lnot,\to,\land,\lor,$ etc., from which the truth tables of larger sentences are calculated. These are indeed definitions, so there is no notion of proving them from simpler notions. You can think of them as giving meanings to the connectives.

(However, we may choose to define certain connectives in terms of others, in which case we'd no longer call them "primitive". For instance if we define $A\lor B$ as $\lnot(\lnot A\land \lnot B)$, we can derive what the truth table for $\lor$ is in terms of the tables for $\lnot$ and $\land$.)

Comment: Another interpretation of the question would be: Does, e.g. the truth table for the $\to$ connective need proof -- in which case the answer is: No, that truth table is the _definition_ of the connective's semantics.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, you're right (and, check-mark notwithstanding, re-reading the original question, I'm inclined to agree with your interpretation).

Comment: Yes, I was asking about connectives, I didn't know those are what they were called. I've always just called them "Boolean operators" but maybe that's wrong.

Comment: @user525966 "Connectives" is usually the word when talking about the symbols as used in a formal language, but I think "boolean operators" is a reasonable term for the boolean functions represented by the truth tables for the connectives. If you'd called "$\land$" a Boolean operator I wouldn't blink an eye unless the distinction were actually important in the context and I was feeling really pedantic.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Sorry to bug you again on an older question. When we say these truth tables for the connectives are definitions, are these also the "interpretations" of those connectives? Or is an interpretation just a single row of an already-defined truth table? For example is the truth table for $a \land b$ itself an "interpretation" of what that connective represents, or are there $4$ interpretations given an already-defined truth table?

Comment: @user525966 If you’re using the word “interpretation” in the in the technical sense, e.g. “a formula is valid if it’s true in any interpretation,” then no. We separate logical symbols (like the connectives) from nonlogical symbols (like the propositional variables) and only the non-logical symbols have different meanings under different interpretations. In classical propositional logic, an interpretation is an assignment of truth values to the propositional variables, and then truth values are induced on formulas by the *fixed* truth tables for the connectives.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen So an interpretation then is just a particular row of a truth table? i.e. some specific and arbitrary selection of true/false values for the propositional variables? For example a=true, b=false in a wff "a and b"

Comment: @user525966 That’s the right idea and very close. It is an assignment for *all* of the propositional variables. Whereas a row in the truth table is only a partial assignment on the variables that actually occur in the sentence.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I don't understand then. When we talk about "all interpretations" I assumed this meant "every row of the truth table"? How is a row only a partial assignment? What I mean is like if we have $(a \land b) \lor c$ then an interpretation would be one of the $2^3$ rows of its truth table.

Comment: @user525966 You have the right idea and I don’t want to scare you off of it. All I’m saying what about $d$, $e,$ $f,$ etc? Usually we have a countably infinite collection of propositional variables and an interpretation is an assignment to all of them. Of course for a given sentence only the assignments of the variables that actually occur in the sentence matter, and the rows of the truth table represent all the possibilities for those variables.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen So an interpretation applies to *all* variables in a language, and it just so happens that only the variables involved in the wff are what we care about? The interpretation then is not done with respect to a wff per se, but with respect to... the language? The premises? The truth functionals/truth tables / $\models$ symbol?

Comment: @user525966 with respect to the language. Languages have interpretations. (And remember what I said about the distinction between logical and non-logical symbols.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen By that do you mean there are infinitely many interpretations where $a$ and $b$ are true in order to make $a \land b$ true, because of all the other variables ($c, d, e, ...$) that are true/false and don't happen to apply here? This is the "class"?

Comment: @user525966 Yes, exactly.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen But on Wikipedia here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Generic_description_of_a_propositional_calculus it defines a propositional calculus in terms of its atomic variables, connectives, axioms, and inference rules -- is this all syntax-only? Where do the truth tables fit in? Can a propositional calculus have many different systems of truth tables?

Comment: @user525966 yes, that’s all syntax and the truth tables are on the semantic side. It is possible to give this language different kinds of semantics. The closest one in practice that might be construed as “different systems of truth tables” would be multivalued logic.

Answer (score 0):

A proof table is just a specific representation of a logical formula. So you might use truth tables to define a logical formula. On the other hand, if your logical formula is defines by other means, a truth table for that formula needs a proof.

For example consider the formula
$$ (A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (C \wedge D).$$
This already is a well-defined logical expression. If you now provide a truth table you have to prove that it correctly represents the formula, i.e. you have to calculate the formula, given different inputs.

On the other hand, defining
$$ A \wedge B$$
is normally done by providing a truth table, so here the truth table serves as a definition, because $A \wedge B$ does not have already have a meaning.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, which seems a little vague. Could you explain under what circumstances a truth table needs a proof?

Answer (score 0):

Truth tables are often used to define the various logical operators ($\neg,\land,\lor, \implies, \iff$), but they can also be derived from various rules of logical inference. See, for example, my [blog posting](http://www.dcproof.com/IfPigsCanFly.html) where I use the principles of direct proof, proof by contradiction, detachment (modus ponens) and the removal of double negations to derive, among other things, the truth table for material implication.